# The break statement - Stuck in a loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

**Objectives**

Familiarize the student with:
- using the break statement in loops;
- reflecting real-life situations in computer code.

**Scenario**

The break statement is used to exit/terminate a loop.
Using the while loop, design a program that continuously asks the user to enter a secret word (e.g.,"You're stuck in an infinite loop! Enter a secret word to leave the loop:") unless the user enters "chupacabra" as the secret exit word, in which case the message "You've successfully left the loop" should be printed to the screen, and the loop should terminate.
Don't print any of the words entered by the user. Use the concept of conditional execution and the break statement.

```
'''
Lab 2.2.22.1 - While loops with 'break' keyword use.
'''
secret_word = str(input("You're stuck in an infinite loop!\nEnter a secret word to leave the loop."))
while secret_word != "chupacabra":
    print("You're stuck in an infinite loop!\nEnter a secret word to leave the loop.")
    if secret_word == "chupacabra":
        print("You've successfully left the loop.")
'''
just keeps printing out both lines continuosly - in a loop.
'''
```

**Problem**

When I run this program, it prints the first 2 lines and waits for an input. If the input matches the var, it doesn't display the "left the loop" string, it just does nothing. If I enter anything other than the correct secret word, it just keeps on printing in a never ending loop those first two lines again.

I'm stuck on how to use the while loop. I only want to do 2 things, print A if the input does not equal the var, and print B if the input does match the var. But everything I've read about the while loops is giving the while something to do, then the if or elif or else get something else to do each.

I'm struggling with this because I don't know how to write this loop so that while doesn't have to do anything, does this make sense?

I'm doing a python course atm, so please bear with me. This is not part of any exams or graded work, but I would rather understand what I'm doing wrong first please.

Comment: While loops assume the conditional changes.  Do you ever change the value of `secret_word`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read for `secret_word` in loop, and use break to exit when it matches wanted :

```
secret_word = ""
while True:
    secret_word = input("You're stuck in an infinite loop!\nEnter a secret word to leave the loop.")
    if secret_word == "chupacabra":
        print("You've successfully left the loop.")
        break
```

Comment: yeah, you are correct, but then this is conditional loop :)

Comment: I know that , typo

Comment: well, you're not stuck when you're out :P

Comment: I'd put the `print` statement after the loop.  That way it is technically correct.

Comment: It's technically correct both ways

Comment: Considering that the statement is clearly within the loop block, it isn't, it's a conditional within the loop.  Functionally it's the same, but what if the loop changed, the message could be left as it is, but with different functionality in the loop (and not breaking out).  That bug would be much more difficult to implement if the "you are outside the loop" statement was actually _outside_ the loop.